# Using more than one instances of WebDriverWait in Selenium WebDriver

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

Suppose, I have declared `WebDriverWait` in a Setup method with `timeout = 60` seconds:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
```

And I used the same to wait for some elements in `Test` method.

Now, for some reason I want to create another `WebDriverWait` instance with `timeout = 30` seconds in `Test` method.

```
public void TestMethod()
{    
     //Some code

     //Wait for element using 'wait' 

     //Some code

     WebDriverWait localWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));

     //Wait for some element using 'localWait'

     //Some code

     //Wait for some element using 'wait' 

}
```

So my question is - is it safe to use more than one instances of `WebDriverWait` in C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem with that. You can also use `wait` in `TestMethod()` together with `localWait`.

```
public void TestMethod()
{ 
     WebDriverWait localWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
     localWait.until(ExpectedCondition a);
     wait.until(ExpectedCondition b);
     // more code
}
```

Comment: But when I wait for element using 'localWait', it takes about 40 seconds. (Note: I am using Implicit wait for 30 secs)

Comment: @amitbobade You defined it for 30 seconds, which is close. It might look little longer because selenium is delayed on something else. The delay is not caused by the other `wait`.